# Is there a way to set up data validation at the data entry level or restrict the entry to a choice set in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I’m wondering if there is a way to set up data validation at the data entry level or restrict the entry to a choice set in CartoDB.

Scenario: I want to display categorical data in a Visualization and continually update the database/Table. So… I add a point to my dataset/Table. Then, I click on it and edit the data. I now want to enter values for the various attributes for that point.

The problem: I can do it, but I don’t have any validation feature to restrict what I enter (other than if the attribute is set as “number”, “boolean", or “date”). I want to limit what I can enter to a choice set (e.g., like in with drop-down menu). If I could have the world, so to speak, I would love to have a survey form type of data entry feature – complete with “multiple choice”, “select all that apply”, formatting checks, and maybe even logic.

Question 1: Is this possible with CartoDB?

Question 2: Is there a way I could set this up, e.g., with embedding a survey form in the map pop-up window? I want the data to go straight into the CartoDB dataset/table that drives my Visualizations. I suppose I may be able to do this directly using a survey and have CartoDB reference or sync with that dataset/Table… but I want to be able to manually locate/pin the point on a map (to get Lat/Lon), and I don’t know of a survey platform that is capable of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question you definitely can do this via **CartoDB.js** which is the library that the CartoDB service uses. Specifically for the infowindows interactivity you need, you'd first have to [create a map with CartoDB.js](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/create_map_cartodbjs.html) and the [set up your custom interactivity for the infowindows](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/custom_interactivity.html) in order to validate and format the data inside the infowindow.

In the case you would only need to embed a survey with no interaction, you can work with html templates via the CartoDB UI.

Comment: All this is covered in the [documentation](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html) and the [tutorial examples](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is helpful (although I have some learning and customization to do I suppose).

Answer (score 2):

Another complement to this answer.

If you actual schema validation at the database level, then you have all the power of PostgreSQL, with range types and constraints.

Check out http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html

This will ensure that the data you enter gets validated at the database level.

This can be very handy on complex applications.